# Error deploying net core API to AWS Elastic Beanstalk server

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-ec2, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I compiled and publish to a folder my net core solution. After that I tried to deploy it to a Elastic Beanstalk environment as a zip file but when I upload and implement my project the environment sets the state "Degraded" and getting a lot of errors like these:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpNXr.png)

I've tried publish and upload my proyect as Framework dependent and self-contained but I'm getting same errors. Is there any solution for this?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the EB logs to identify the command that fails?

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying to Windows or Linux? If Windows then you have to include the deployment manifest file in the deployment bundle. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-manifest.html